# Meu button onClick não está funcionando no next js

Tags: react

os buttões com onClick estão funcionando normalmente em outros componentes, menos nesse caso em específico.

obs: estou usando o Styled Components para esse componentes em volta.

```
import ContainerForm from '../components/form/ContainerForm';
import ContentForm from '../components/form/ContentForm';
export default function Form(){

    const Teste = ()=>{
       <div>
            <input type="button" onClick={()=>console.log('ok')} 
            value="clique"/>
        </div>
    }
    return <ContainerForm><ContentForm><Teste/></ContentForm></ContainerForm>
}
```

Comment: O input, por padrão, tem seu tipo definido como 'text'. Para que isso seja um botão, você precisa definir o type com o valor 'button' ou 'submit'.

Comment: Eu já havia feito assim, errei com dessa vez em esquecer do type="submit", mas atualizei minha pergunta. Na verdade, mesmo com o botão corretamente implementado a função chamada no onClick não funciona apenas dentro deste componente. Fora dele on em outras telas funciona corretamente.

Comment: pode disponibilizar `ContainerForm` e `ContentForm`?

Comment: O  seu componente 'Teste' deveria retornar algo, provavelmente está tendo esse erro no seu console ( se não estiver explodindo na  interface como  o CRA faz ).

Outra possibilidade pode ser que no seu styled component, algo esteja sobrepondo seu botão. Confira isso pelo inspetor de elementos do browser e veja se há algo acima do seu botão recebendo a interação.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Teste = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" onClick={()=>console.log('ok')} value="clique"/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

O Componente Teste não está retornando, então, o botão não aparece na tela